# How to handle missing key in dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary with keys and values. Unfortunately, some keys are not available for some dictionaries. E.g. year 1969 is not available. When I run the code, the output is stuck as there is no "year" key.
How can I make the program continue with 1970 and so on?

```
testdict = [{"brand": "ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1964},
            {"brand": "ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1965},
            {"brand": "ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1966},
            {"brand": "ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1967},
            {"brand": "ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1968},
            {"brand": "ford", "model": "Mustang"},
            {"brand": "ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1970},
            {"brand": "ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1971},
            {"brand": "ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1972},
            {"brand": "ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1973},
            {"brand": "ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1974},]

for x in testdict:
    print(x["brand"], x["year"])
```

I am getting this output:

```
ford 1964
ford 1965
ford 1966
ford 1967
ford 1968

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-8175c2e2026a> in <module>()
      1 for x in testdict:
----> 2     print(x["brand"], x["year"])

KeyError: 'year'
```

How to skip the values which are not present in the dictionary?

Answer (score 16):

`get` is useful:

```
{ "exist": True }["notExist"]
# => KeyError
{ "exist": True }.get("notExist")
# => None
{ "exist": True }.get("notExist", 17)
# => 17

for x in testdict:
    print(x["brand"], x.get("year", "N/A"))
```

Also, `in`:

```
"notExist" in { "exist": True }
# => False

for x in testdict:
    if "year" in x:
        print(x["brand"], x["year"])
```

You can also catch the exception with `except`, following the EAFP principle (easier to ask for forgiveness than permission):

```
for x in testdict:
    try:
        print(x["brand"], x["year"])
    except KeyError:
        pass # didn't want to print that anyway
```

Answer (score 5):

One of the choice that we have available is to put the code in try-except block. For your case, it should be like

```
for data in testlist:
    try:
        print(data['brand'],data['year'])
    except KeyError as err:
        # Do something to handle the error
```

Alternatively, if you just want a particular value to return when the key is not found in the dictionary, you can use the get member method of the dict class as

```
dictionary.get('Ask for a key',default='Return this in case key not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of try and except :

```
for x in testdict:
    try:
        print(x["brand"], x["year"])
    except(KeyError):
        continue
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set a default by using `setdefault` that will be turned if the key is not found. This works well if you do not have many keys but want to keep referencing the keys you have.

```
testdict.setdefault('brand', 'Key missing')
testdict.setdefault('year', 'Key missing')

for x in testdict:
    print(x["brand"], x["year"])
```

If you have a few keys and don't want to keep repeating the same code you could setup a loop to iterate through a list of key names.

```
list_of_keys = ['brand', 'year']
for key in list_of_key:
    testdict.setdefault(key, 'Key missing')

for x in testdict:
    print(x["brand"], x["year"])
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this for code.

```
for val in testdict:
    if len(val) == 3:
        print(val["brand"],val["year"])
```

Output:

```
ford 1964
ford 1965
ford 1966
ford 1967
ford 1968
ford 1970
ford 1971
ford 1972
ford 1973
ford 1974
```

Comment: If 'model' is missing but other elements exist, this will not work