# How to deal with a key that is present and missing at the same type?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am pulling data via API in a JSON response.

Here is how the data looks like

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "register_overwrite_notify": false,
      "owner_id": "example",
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looking to save each owner id into a list however sometimes the `owner_id` does not exist.

How do I continue saving each owner id as long as the key exists and then if the key does not exist how do I "ignore" that record?

Here is some sample of code but this saves an empty list:

```
for each in users['data']:
    while 'owner_id' in users:
        accounts.append((each['owner_id']))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle missing key in Python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928345/how-to-handle-missing-key-in-python-dictionary)

Comment: `accounts = [user["user_id"] for user in users if "user_id" in user]`

Comment: `owner_id` is a potential key in `users['data']`, not `users` itself. `while 'owner_id' in users['data']` would be an infinite loop if the key were present; you want `if`, not `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following solution:

```
data = [
    {
        "register_overwrite_notify": False,
        "owner_id": "example",
    }
]

accounts = []
for each in data:
    if each.get("owner_id") is not None:
        accounts.append(each.get("owner_id"))
```

All it does is it first checks if the `dict.get()` method returns something, otherwise it returns `None`, and the `owner_id` is not added to the `accounts` list.

Comment: Yes this is great, it saves all records which have a owner_id key. Thanks so much!

Comment: You don't need the `is not None` part. This can also be done more succinctly with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions): `accounts = [each['owner_id'] for each in users['data'] if each.get("owner_id")]`.

Comment: @martineau There are more concise ways of doing it but it becomes less readable imho

Comment: True, but I find the list comp *more* readable than your code in this case.

Comment: Sure - just depends on how familiar you are with python concepts. :)

Comment: @martineau, `is not None` may not be necessary here but sometimes there is unexpected behavior with `get` method (for e.g. when doing `if d.get(1):` where `d` is `{1:0}`.

Comment: @d.b: I didn't say it's *never* required. In cases were the retrieved data itself might have a valid but a falsy value, then such additional checking might be necessary to differentiate (or a default other than `None` provided to the dictionary [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this iteratively if you want:

```
my_list = []

resp = users.get("data", {})
if resp.get("data"):
    data = resp.get("data", [])
    if data:
        for item in data:
            owner_id = item.get("owner_id", None)
            if owner_id:
                my_list.append(owner_id)
```